# how can I set my GitHub project public but no one is allowed to change and push it but me?

Tags: github

I uploaded my project to GitHub, everybody is allowed to clone it and I am OK with that, but why other can change and push the project to GitHub

this is my project :

https://github.com/tahadev/NativeFormMakerAndroid.git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't happen, if you don't set the collaborators of the project, they can't merge code into production, and others will need to make a pull request that you will need to accept in order to merge code with master.

Comment: I may have my github user pass on my android studio 
I cloned it but I guess I forgot to remove my user pass

Comment: You and only you have write access to your repo with your authentication credentials, anyone in your pc with your Android Studio opened can push code to that repo (because you are already logged in with your git account), but, anonymous users that clone your repo from outside your credentials cant push code into your repository